# Turn on optional filters and parameters in BIRT

Tags: birt

I'm currently developing a dynamic report in BIRT. I work with a cube and a cross table to present my data, but now I want to add some parameters. I use the filter function in my dataset and that works fine. But the problem is that you need to fill in every parameter otherwise he gets no information.

So for example, if I want to view only the bank and not the branches of a specific bank, I can't see anything because the branchname is blank.

How can I adjust optional parameters in BIRT?

Answer (score 0):

I had to read this question a couple times, I think I know what you are asking.

When you want a user to be able to provide only one of several possible parameters.  Use a like query with a wildcard default value.

In my first parameter window I have a drop down with the Assignment, this would be similar to your 'bank' I have a few hundred very specific values here.  If they pick this, they only get what they selected (*no beginning or ending wildcard*).

The user also has the option of getting a more focused return by populating other parameters with non-wildcard or wildcard supported entries (*i.e. %jones% in the name field*).

**Beware if they run the query with all the wildcards in place they will get all the data, ensure that your database and report can survive that query or put in limiters.**

```
where ASSIGNMENT like ?
and ADDRESS like ?
and CONTACT like ?
```

[image]

Comment: But when I change my bankname from '%' to another value, he automatically changes the branchname because it's a cascading parameter group. Is this solution also possible for such grouping?

Comment: Try it and see what happens.